# Fancybox 2: styling direct link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm having some issues figuring out how to style fancybox.  At the moment my options that I've set are piecemeal from other locations.

I found something on creating a direct link to a fancybox image and triggering the lightbox functionality which is this:

```
<!-- Fancybox remote link trigger -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisHash = window.location.hash;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(window.location.hash) {
                $(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
            }
            $('.fancylink').fancybox();

        }); // ready
</script>
```

This works great.  I set up an id in each link and I can get a direct url that triggers fancybox when you go to it.  The problem though is I don't understand how to style fancybox correctly, and honestly the documentation is pretty weak.  I managed to style my main fancybox implementation through more piecemeal here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisHash = window.location.hash;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.hash) {
            $(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
        }
            $('.fancylink').fancybox();
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers : { 
                title : { type : 'inside' }
            }, // helpers
            beforeShow : function() {
                this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '') + '<br>' + '<span style="font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif; color:#bfbfbf; font-size: 12px;">' + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;  
            } // beforeShow
        }); // fancybox
    }); // ready
</script>
```

This has all the proper options and styling I want with a secondary line that displays photo count, but I don't get that for my direct link code up above.  I tried combining the two but no luck, I either bork it or don't get a result rendered.  I'm assuming I CAN combine these two chunks together, but I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  just have to provide the fancybox options to your working code like this:

EDIT. fixed prevuous code

```
<!-- Fancybox remote link trigger -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   var thisHash = window.location.hash;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(thisHash).fancybox({
            helpers : { 
               title : { type : 'inside' }
            }, // helpers
            beforeShow : function() {
               this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '') + '<br>' + '<span style="font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif; color:#bfbfbf; font-size: 12px;">' + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;  
            } // beforeShow
        });
        if(window.location.hash) {
            $(thisHash).trigger('click');
        }
    }); // ready
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, but it breaks fancybox.  If I click on a link, it goes to a new page with just the image.

Comment: Have you checked if the console/firebug throws some error?

Comment: Only thing I get from console (chrome) is:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: [pathOfImage.jpg]

Comment: Not sure what you changed, but trying your updated code did not work.  Same error as before (and same result; clicking a link goes to a new page with image, and not activate fancybox).

Comment: Oh wait, I screwed up.  This actually works perfectly for a direct link to the image, but if I go to my index.php and click fancybox links, they're broken and link directly to the image instead of launching fancybox.

Comment: Never mind.  I tried it again.  I think I was dealing with caching issues.  This works perfectly.  Thank you.